# Topological Conditions Equivalent to "Very Disconnected"

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology

**Definition:** Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, where the set $X$ has more than one element. Suppose that for every pair of distinct elements $a, b \in X$, there exists a separation $(A,B)$ of $X$ such that $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Then we say $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is **very disconnected**.

Is this condition (being "very disconnected") equivalent to another, well-known one?

The definition above is my own, but I suspect it is equivalent to some pre-existing notion (e.g., a $T_{n \frac{1}{2}}$ space for some $n$). Here are a few propositions that I have proved about v.d. spaces:

1. Any very disconnected space is disconnected.
2. Any discrete space is very disconnected.
3. There are very disconnected spaces that are not discrete.
4. If a space is very disconnected, then all singletons are closed.
5. All singletons closed does not imply the space is very disconnected.

Comment: Do you mean "totally disconnected" perhaps?

Comment: A separation is a decomposition into two disjoint sets that are simultaneously open and closed?

Comment: @DanielFischer Right: $(A,B)$ is a separation of $(X, \mathcal{T})$ provided $A \cap B = \emptyset$; both $A,B$ are nonempty, clopen sets; and $A \cup B = X$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My recollection is that "very disconnected" is different from "totally disconnected." If I have misremembered and you can see (show) them as the same, then I would gladly accept that as an answer.

Comment: No, I was just asking whether you may have meant "totally disconnected". Both terms would translate almost the same in Hebrew, so I wanted to be sure that a cross-lingual barrier didn't cause any issues here.

Comment: Okay, then a very disconnected space is certainly totally disconnected. I'm not sure yet whether it's in fact equivalent, or stronger. I suspect it's stronger, but can't come up with an example quickly.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, the definition here ("very disconnected") is one that I came up with as a part of a top. course that used the closure axioms. Probably v.d. implies t.d. or vice-versa (I see Daniel Fischer has now made a remark to this effect.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Consider $(\mathbb{Z}^+, \mathcal{T})$ where all finite sets are closed, and all infinite sets containing $1$ are closed. I believe this gives a very disconnected space. Furthermore, the nontrivial set $\{2, 3, 4, \ldots\}$ is a connected subset: it cannot be written as a disjoint union of two closed sets, since at least one of them must be infinite but not contain $1$. Thus, I do not think v.d. implies t.d.

Comment: $\{2,\, 3,\, \ldots\}$ is not connected. Disconnected means a set can be written as a disjoint union of two _relatively_ closed/open subsets. Any partition of that set into one finite set and its complement is such.

Comment: Oh, right, the subset would be given the subspace topology; thanks.

Comment: I think this property is normally called being *totally separated*. It is stronger than being totally disconnected.

Comment: @ChrisEagle A ha, this looks like what I was looking for. (The one difference being that my definition has $|X| > 1$.) Thanks. (If you include this as an answer I will accept it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a relation where $x\sim y$ if there is no separation of the space $X$ between $x$ and $y$, or equivalently, each clopen set containing $x$ also contains $y$. It is very easy to check that this is an equivalence relation and that the equivalence class of $x$ is the intersection of all clopen neighborhoods. This class is called *quasi-component* of $x$.

This relation is coarser than the relation defining connectedness, so a quasi-component is a disjoint union of components. There are conditions under which the components and the quasi-components coincide, for example when $X$ is compact Hausdorff, or when there are only finitely many quasi-components. It also holds if the components are open (which is the case for locally connected spaces or spaces with only a finite number of components.)

An example of a totally disconnected space, i.e. all components are singletons, where the quasi-components are not the singletons is the sequence 
$$\left\{\frac1n\mid n\in\Bbb N\right\}\cup\{0,0'\}$$
converging to two distinct zeros, where the neighborhood base of $0$ is given by the intervals $[0,\epsilon),\ \epsilon>0$ and similarly for $0'$. Then each $0$ is a component but the quasi-component of $0$ is $\{0,0'\}$

**Edit:** @Chris Eagle points out that a space where the quasi-components are the singletons is called *totally separated*.

Comment: Great; thanks Stefan!