# Cantor's Teepee is Totally Disconnected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $C^\prime$ be the Cantor set and let $C = C^\prime \times \{0\}$ (viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$). For $c \in C$, let $L(c)$ denote the half-closed line segment connecting $(c,0)$ to $(\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2})$ (including $(c,0)$ but excluding $(\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2})$).

If $c \in C$ is $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, or an endpoint of an interval deleted in the Cantor set, let $X_{c} = \{ (x,y) \in L(c) : y \in \mathbb{Q} \}$. For all other $c \in C$, let $X_{c} = \{ (x,y) \in L(c) : y \notin \mathbb{Q} \}$.

Cantor's Teepee is the set $\bigcup_{c \in C} X_{c}$ equipped with the subspace topology inherited from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I've found several references to the fact that Cantor's Teepee is totally disconnected, but I cannot quite prove it.

---

It was brought to my attention in the comments that I had taken the wrong definition for totally disconnected when first working on this problem, as demonstrated in the following example. The property I had been attempting to prove was [totally separated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435481/topological-conditions-equivalent-to-very-disconnected), which lead to the quandary I was experiencing below.

> In particular, I cannot seem to separate two points that belong to the
>   same $X_c$. For concreteness:
>
> > What are two separated open sets $A$ and $B$ such that
> >
> > - $A$ and $B$ witness the disconnectedness of Cantor's Teepee,
> > - $(0,0) \in A$, and
> > - $(\tfrac{1}{4}, \tfrac{1}{4}) \in B$?
>
> Notice $(0,0), (\tfrac{1}{4}, \tfrac{1}{4}) \in X_0$. Presumably the
>   method that works for this example can be easily modified to work for
>   any pair of points belonging to the same $X_c$.

Comment: Do $0$ and $1$ count as endpoints of intervals deleted in the Cantor set?

Comment: @AlexBecker I've updated the definition to include $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ as endpoints. Whether they are included or not should not affect the total disconnectedness.

Comment: I recall that the purpose of this example is to show that a **connected** set can become totally disconnected after removing one point, namely $(1/2,1/2)$. Have you removed said point? Also, [on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/36017).

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills Rather than define the "leaky tent" and the remove the point $(1/2,1/2)$ to obtain the teepee, I removed the point from the beginning by explicitly defining $L(c)$ to exclude $(1/2,1/2)$. I saw the MathOverflow question, but it does not contain a proof of total disconnectedness.

Comment: It seems the thesis takes "totally disconnected" to mean "quasicomponents are singletons". I think the more common definition is "components are singletons", which is a weaker property.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills I think you are correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $T$ be the Cantor teepee. Every point $t\in T$ lies on unique interval of the form $[c, (1/2, 1/2)]$, where $c\in C'$. The map $f: t\mapsto c$ is continuous on $T$. Suppose $A\subset T$ is a connected subset. Then $f(A)$ is also connected. Since $C'$ is totally disconnected, $f(A)$ is a single point. Thus, $A$ is contained in subset $L_c$. But each $L_c$ is clearly totally disconnected. Hence, $A$ is a single point. Thus, $T$ is totally disconnected. qed

Answer (score 3):

The following proof is a clunkier version of that given by studiosus, but I provide some details that I think will be helpful for my students who are involved with this problem.

---

Let $Y$ be any subset of Cantor's Teepee containing more than one point. Our goal is to produce two sets $A$ and $B$ such that

- $A$ and $B$ are separated open sets in the subspace topology induced by $Y$ and
- $Y = A \cup B$.

Since Cantor's Teepee is itself a subspace of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, we may revise these conditions to read

- $A$ and $B$ are separated open sets in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and
- $Y \subseteq A \cup B$.

Now, suppose $Y$ contains points $p \in X_a$ and $q \in X_c$ with $a \neq c$ (that is, $Y$ witnesses more than one "strand" of the teepee). Choose any real number $b$ such that $a < b < c$ and $b$ lies in a deleted interval of the Cantor set. To obtain the separated open sets $A$ and $B$, take any open set containing $Y$ (or even the entire teepee) and "split" it along the line connecting $(b,0)$ and $(1/2,1/2)$ (see figure).

[image]

Suppose instead that all points of $Y$ belong to a single strand. The $y$-coordinates of points belonging to this strand are either all rational or all irrational. In either case, we can easily separate the strand by passing our open sets through a point $r$ with $y$-coordinate of the opposite type (see figure).

[image]

Therefore every subset of Cantor's teepee with more than one point is disconnected, which is to say Cantor's teepee is totally disconnected.