# A very weird connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: connectedness

Is it possible to construct a connected subset of the plane with the property that removal of any single point makes it totally disconnected? Any answer is appreciated..Thanks!!

Comment: I suppose that a singleton set might satisfy the definition trivially.  After removal, the resulting set has the property that any two points in it can be separated...

Comment: Yes, the Knaster-Kuratowski fan is such an example.

Comment: @Hayden The Knaster-Kuratowski fan only becomes totally disconnected if we remove a certain point $p$, not if we remove any point.

Comment: Google "explosion point" along with "connected".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Good point, the OP did say "any".

Answer (score 2):

No, it is impossible, if we exclude the trivial case of a singleton. Such a point is called a [dispersion point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_point). A space can only have one dispersion point. So we cannot remove **any** single point to obtain a totally disconnected space.

However, if we only want that the removal of **one** single point makes the space totally disconnected, then the [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan), or [Cantor's teepee](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758570/cantors-teepee-is-totally-disconnected) is a well-known example.

Comment: Dear all, thanks for the comments. I would assume that we are all interested in NON-TRIVIAL examples. So the question can be corrected as: Can one find a non-trivial connected subset $A$ of the plane such that $A\{x}$ is disconnected for every $x\in A$. So what we are looking for is a non-tivial subset of the plane with the property that Whatever point you remove from the set, it becomes totally disconnected.  I'm sorry for any misleading..Thanks again!

Comment: Dear Aneesh, there is no non-trivial subset of the plane with this property - see my answer.